# ggplot2: How to indicate data subsets in a time series geom_bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar plot based on a time series of dependent variable observations. However, I would also like to include in the graph some indication on the subsets of the data. The subsets are defined by explanatory variables that do not completely correspond to the dependent variable.

For example:

```r
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(year = 1995:2020) %>%
    mutate(values = runif(26, 0, 1),
           dumOne = case_when(year %in% 2000:2010 ~ 1, T ~ 0),
           dumTwo = case_when(year %in% 2003:2009 ~ 1, T ~ 0))

ggplot(df, aes(year, values)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

To this graph I would like to add horizontal lines that correspond to variables `dumOne` and `dumTwo` and possibly some explanatory text. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geom_segment` function is an option here.  Just define the start and stop points and the y value of where to the lines.  I used the max and min functions to locate the start and end years.  I plot the lines near the top but this is easily adjusted.

```
df <- data.frame(year = 1995:2020) %>%
  mutate(values = runif(26, 0, 1),
         dumOne = case_when(year %in% 2000:2010 ~ 1, T ~ 0),
         dumTwo = case_when(year %in% 2003:2009 ~ 1, T ~ 0))


#difine the start and stopping points
domin<-min(df$year[df$dumOne==1])
domax<-max(df$year[df$dumOne==1])
dtmin<-min(df$year[df$dumTwo==1])
dtmax<-max(df$year[df$dumTwo==1])

#Create dataframe of values and labels
seg<-data.frame(x=c(domin, dtmin), xend=c(domax, dtmax), y=c(max(df$values)-0.05, max(df$values)-0.1), 
                Label=c('dumOne', "dumTwo"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(year, values)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_segment(data=seg, aes(x=x, xend=xend, y=y, yend=y, color=Label), size=2)
```

[image]